# Returning the first X records in a postgresql query with a unique field

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, postgresql

Ok so I'm having a bit of a learning moment here and after figuring out *A* way to get this to work, I'm curious if anyone with a bit more postgres experience could help me figure out a way to do this without doing a whole lotta behind the scene rails stuff (or doing a single query for each item i'm trying to get)... now for an explaination:

Say I have 1000 records, we'll call them "Instances", in the database that have these fields:

```
id
user_id
other_id
```

I want to create a method that I can call that pulls in 10 instances that all have a unique other_id field, in plain english (I realize this won't work :) ):

```
Select * from instances where user_id = 3 and other_id is unique limit 10
```

So instead of pulling in an array of 10 instances where user_id is 3 and you can get multiple instances with the other_id is 5, I want to be able to run a map function on those 10 instances and get back something like [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10].

In theory, I can probably do one of two things currently, though I'm trying to avoid them:

1. Store an array of id's and do individual calls making sure the next call says "not in this array". The problem here is I'm doing 10 individual db queries.
2. Pull in a large chunk of say, 50 instances and sorting through them in ruby-land to find 10 unique ones. This wouldn't allow me to take advantage of any optimizations already done in the database and I'd also run the risk of doing a query for 50 items that don't have 10 unique other_id's and I'd be stuck with those unless I did another query.

Anyways, hoping someone may be able to tell me I'm overlooking an easy option :) I know this is *kind of* optimizing before it's really needed but this function is going to be run over and over and over again so I figure it's not a waste of time right now.

For the record, I'm using Ruby 1.9.3, Rails 3.2.13, and Postgresql (Heroku)

Thanks!

**EDIT**: Just wanted to give an example of a function that technically DOES work (and is number 1 above)

```
def getInstances(limit, user)
  out_of_instances = false
  available = []
  other_ids = [-1] # added -1 to avoid submitting a NULL query

  until other_ids.length == limit || out_of_instances == true

    instance = Instance.where("user_id IS ? AND other_id <> ALL (ARRAY[?])", user.id, other_ids).limit(1)

    if instance != []
      available << instance.first
      other_ids << instance.first.other_id
    else
      out_of_instances = true
    end
  end
end
```

And you would run:

```
getInstances(10, current_user)
```

While this works, it's not ideal because it's leading to 10 separate queries every time it's called :(

Comment: you could `GROUP BY other_id`, no?

Comment: Yep! I was thinking about that, but I'm not sure if you can get a specific number of groups? That's a question, not a statement :) I'm really not sure if something like: "Select * from instances where user_id = 3 group_by other_id limit 10" (horribly pretend syntax) would return 10 instances grouped by other_id, or 10 groups (which is what I'd want) with one instance each.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a single SQL query, it can be achieved easily with `SELECT DISTINCT ON...` which is a PostgreSQL-specific feature.

See http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-select.html

> SELECT DISTINCT ON ( expression [, ...] ) keeps only the first row of
>   each set of rows where the given expressions evaluate to equal. The
>   DISTINCT ON expressions are interpreted using the same rules as for
>   ORDER BY (see above). Note that the "first row" of each set is
>   unpredictable unless ORDER BY is used to ensure that the desired row
>   appears first

With your example:

```
 SELECT DISTINCT ON (other_id) * 
 FROM instances
 WHERE user_id = 3 
 ORDER BY other_id LIMIT 10
```

Comment: Flawless :) That works perfect! Had no idea DISTINCT ON existed so thanks for teaching me something new! For anyone wondering, here's what it looks like when I added that into my rails app: `Instance.select("DISTINCT ON (other_id) *").where({:user_id => 3}).order("other_id").limit(10)`

Comment: This does lead me to another question though, which is good, always learning new stuff. I'm now curious if I can avoid having to now check if it's possible to avoid looping through those in ruby-land to do another filter. This seems less likely and hard to explain, so I'll just post another question :) Thanks a TON for the help!

Comment: Just added it here if anyone feels they can help :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21925712/joining-two-separate-queries-in-a-postgresql-query-possible-or-not-possib. @Daniel Verite, I owe you a beer.