# Joining two separate queries in a postgresql ...query... (possible or not possible)

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, postgresql

I got some great help over at [Returning the first X records in a postgresql query with a unique field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21923118/returning-the-first-x-records-in-a-postgresql-query-with-a-unique-field) with an issue that I'm having and trying to optimize as much as I can for now (though I'm usually not a big fan of front-loading the optimization, this is kind of a unique situation).

Imagine three entities in an app:

```
User
Post
Instance # An instance is just a reference to a post
```

The fields look something like this:

```
User
  id
Post
  id
  user_id
  name
Instance
  id
  user_id
  post_id
  helped_by_user_id
```

**Requirements**:

Return 10 instances where:

1. user_id does not equal 3
2. post_id is unique
3. there is no other instance with that post_id and the helped_by_user_id of 3

---

**EDIT:**

I've created an SQLFiddle for this at http://sqlfiddle.com/#!10/7a324/1/0.

For the record, I'm using Ruby 1.9.3, Rails 3.2.13, and Postgresql (Heroku)

Comment: The explanation is a tad confusing. Any chance you can put some actual sample data up and show expected results? http://sqlfiddle.com/ is useful.

Comment: Craig, you're very right... it's a tough one to explain so I threw together a sqlfiddle to better explain it. I'm attaching it to my original post.

Comment: Forgot to save the edit? I don't see it.

Comment: Sorry Craig, should be saved now. Thanks again!

Comment: Thanks. I think part of the problem is that "instance" is an incredibly confusing term for whatever it's supposed to be. What does it actually mean? And why do you create two "instances" when a post is created? Seems like a bizarre schema. I was hoping that having the data set would help it make more sense, but it doesn't really.

Comment: So the usecase is this: a post actually has an image associated with it and I wanted to avoid creating two posts (duplicating the images for storage). An instance in all reality is just a reference to the post. so here's the order (it keeps sending i forget i cant press enter in these comments): 1. User creates post 2. We create two instances that point to that post 3. Another user pulls in a feed of 10 available posts to be helped on. 4. Once a user pulls in that feed we mark that instance as "helped_by" that user. 5. Once a user helps on it, we create another two instances for that post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just so it's easier to read, with 100% of the credit going to @CraigRinger, the final solution that worked great for me was:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (post_id) *
FROM instances i
WHERE i.user_id <> 3
AND i.helped_by_user_id IS NULL
AND NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT 1
  FROM instances ii
  WHERE ii.post_id = i.post_id
  AND ii.helped_by_user_id = 3
)
ORDER BY i.post_id
LIMIT 10;
```

Answer (score 3):

Right, so you want posts written by somebody other than $user where no "instance" (appears to mean "reply") for $user appears. From this set you wish to select ten distinct posts.

If that's an accurate framing of the problem, this does what you want:

```
SELECT *
FROM posts p
WHERE p.user_id <> 3
AND NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT 1
  FROM instances i
  WHERE i.post_id = p.id
  AND i.helped_by_user_id = 3
)
ORDER BY p.id
LIMIT 10;
```

Overall, it feels like the issue here is that the problem isn't really framed clearly. Usually, if you can say in clear English what you want from a data set, it's then quite easy to translate it into useful SQL.

Comment: this helps a TON. It seems like what ended up working perfectly for me is: `SELECT DISTINCT ON (post_id) *
FROM instances i
WHERE i.user_id <> 3
AND i.helped_by_user_id IS NULL
AND NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT 1
  FROM instances ii
  WHERE ii.post_id = i.post_id
  AND ii.helped_by_user_id = 3
)
ORDER BY i.post_id
LIMIT 10;` which returns 10 instances with unique post_id's and it also checks to make sure an instance with that post_id and the user set as the helped_by_user_id does not exist. I've had a lot of trouble framing this question so thanks for bearing with me.

Comment: I've updated my question to better explain it, I was giving too much unhelpful information.